# Simplifying nested cosines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given two real numbers, $a$ and $b$. Is it possible to simplify

> $\cos(a*\cos(bx))$

Such that there are no instances of nested cosines?

Comment: Typically not.  Why would you think you could?